# Haproxy: Need to know all Incoming IP's

Tags: haproxy

I have two web servers running with One load balancer with Haproxy. I need to block IP's that are coming to my load balancer more than often. How do I check all the incoming IP's? Is there a log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see the established connections on a Linux server, use this command (via SSH):

```
netstat -ntu | grep ESTAB | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 10
```

If you want to log more verbose HAProxy activity, use this setting in `haproxy.cfg`:

```
log 127.0.0.1 local0 info
```

You can view the more verbose output in `/var/log/haproxy_0.log`

Comment: Looks promising. Will try and let u know.

Comment: You can simplify your `netstat` command some: `netstat -ntu | awk -F"[ :]*" '/ESTAB/ {a[$6]++} END {for (i in a) print a[i],i}'`

Answer (score 0):

You should try this :

```
echo 'Client IP: '.$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
echo 'Client IP: '.$_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];
```

These commands displays loadbalancer's IP. More at : https://serverfault.com/a/331909

Comment: This is not working. Running them is giving me Client 
IP: .[HTTP_CLIENT_IP]
Client IP: .[REMOTE_ADDR] but not IP